# Spooled output in SQL*Plus with multiple parameters

Tags: oracle, powershell, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I am trying to launch a .sql with SQL*Plus using a Powershell script. For some reason the script does not generate output when i use a second parameter in the command line. It does work when I only use one. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

The Powershell line im using to start sqlplus is as follows:

```
    Run-LocalProcess SQLPLUS "${USER/PASS} @${SQLPATH}\something.sql ${1STPARAMETER} ${2NDPARAMETER}"
```

Where LocalProcess is a function we use to start processes in the CLI. The 1st parameter is the filepath of the spooled output without \ on the end. The 2nd parameter is a number we are trying to add to the spooled output filename.

The .sql we are using is as follows:

```
    set heading off
    set pause off
    set verify off
    set termout off
    set trimspool on
    set feedback off
    set linesize 500 
    set pagesize 0
    set escape ^

column sys_date heading "SystemDate" new_value sys_date format a20;

select  to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') sys_date
from    dual;

column db_name heading "DatabaseName" new_value db_name format a12;

select  d.name db_name
from    v$database d;

spool &1\&2something_&db_name._&sys_date..txt
SOMETHING
spool off
```

The reason im setting escape to ^ is that the standard escape of SQLPLUS is a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

The spool command should start before the query execution starts.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Sqlplus is silent mode, thereby you don't put the content of the banner in your output file

```
Run-LocalProcess SQLPLUS -S "${USER/PASS} @${SQLPATH}\something.sql ${1STPARAMETER} ${2NDPARAMETER}"
```

and like @Sagi said, you need to put the spool before the query.

Comment: Hi, the query is after the spool. I just put "SOMETHING" instead of the query. The spool does generate output when using it with only one parameter (&1). But it doesn't when i use the second aswell. Have also tried running in silent mode which doesnt resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to delimit the second parameter? Instead of '&2something'. shouldn't it be '&2.something'?

contents of doit.sql:

```
set echo on feedback on verify on trimsp on lines 256 pages 5
Prompt Parm 1 is &1
prompt parm 2 is &2
prompt combined is &1\&2something
prompt combined delimited is &1\&2.something
```

Run time:

```
SQL> @doit
SQL> set echo on feedback on verify on trimsp on lines 256 pages 5
SQL> Prompt Parm 1 is &1
Parm 1 is bob
SQL> prompt parm 2 is &2
parm 2 is carol
SQL> prompt combined is &1\&2something
Enter value for 2something: fubar
combined is bob\fubar
SQL> prompt combined delimited is &1\&2.something
combined delimited is bob\carolsomething
```

Comment: This solved the problem. I knew it would be something as simple as this haha. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here my example

```
cat myscript.sql
set heading off
set pause off
set verify off
set termout off
set trimspool on
set feedback off
set linesize 500
set pagesize 0
set escape ^

column sys_date heading "SystemDate" new_value sys_date format a20;

select  to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') sys_date
from    dual;

column db_name heading "DatabaseName" new_value db_name format a12;

select  d.name db_name
from    v$database d;

spool &1.\_\&2._something_&db_name._&sys_date..txt
select * from dual;
spool off
```

Now I execute

```
sqlplus -S "/ as sysdba" @myscript.sql "first" "second"
```

I got

```
[ftpcpl@scglvdoracd0006 ~]$ ls -ltr firs*
-rw-r--r-- 1 ftpcpl dms 2 Jun 18 16:13 
first_second_something_ODCGRC1R_20200618161359.txt
[ftpcpl@scglvdoracd0006 ~]$ cat first_second_something_ODCGRC1R_20200618161359.txt
X
```

Regards